# .Net CAD 2014,custom ribbon menu can not show

Tags: .net, autocad

I create a ribbon menu, and I see the debug information,it added to cad ribbon panel succeed,The last tab is created by me.But it doesn`t show in CAD，What happened? and there are 57 tabs in it,but CAD does not show 57 tabs, only 9.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpqGK.png)
The code is here:

```
RibbonControl rc = RibbonServices.RibbonPaletteSet.RibbonControl;
            foreach (var tab in root.TabRibbons)
            {
                RibbonTab rt = new RibbonTab();
                rt.Title = tab.Name;
                rt.Id = tab.Id;
                //rc.Tabs.Add(rt);
                rc.Tabs.Insert(0, rt);
                rt.IsActive = tab.IsActive;
                rt.IsActive = false;
                rt.Name = "BridgeWise";
                rt.AllowTearOffContextualPanels = false;

                foreach (var panel in tab.panels)
                {
                    RibbonPanelSource rps = new RibbonPanelSource();
                    rps.Title = panel.Name;
                    RibbonPanel rp = new RibbonPanel();
                    rp.Source = rps;
                    rt.Panels.Add(rp);
                    foreach (var button in panel.buttons)
                    {
                        if (button.ButType=="Separator")
                        {
                            RibbonSeparator rs = new RibbonSeparator();
                            rs.SeparatorStyle = RibbonSeparatorStyle.Invisible;
                            rp.Source.Items.Add(rs);
                        }
                        else if (button.ButType == "Button")
                        {
                            RibbonButton rb = new RibbonButton();
                            rb.Text = button.Name;
                            rb.CommandParameter = button.Cmd;
                            rb.CommandHandler = new AutoCadRunCmd();
                            rb.Image = ImageHelper.GetImage(button.Image);
                            rb.Description = button.Description;
                            rb.ShowImage = true;
                            rb.ShowText = button.IsText;
                            if (button.IsText)
                            {
                                rb.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
                            }

                            rb.LargeImage = ImageHelper.GetImage(button.LargeImage);
                            rb.Size = button.IsLarge ? RibbonItemSize.Large : RibbonItemSize.Standard;

                            rp.Source.Items.Add(rb);
                        }
                        else if (button.ButType == "NewLine")
                        {
                            RibbonRowBreak rrb = new RibbonRowBreak();
                            rp.Source.Items.Add(rrb);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }        
    }
```

why?Is somesone can help me.Thanks!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc1Dj.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: [enter answer description here](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: sorry,I add the code.